# Mixed case domain name could be nightmare?

Tags: domain-name

Marketing people wants to print the domain name in mixed case. I am kinda in doubt with this- any chance would cause technical issue?

Comment: Make sure your marketing people are aware that people will ignore their capitalisation, which could lead to the proverbial "ExpertsExchange" and "PenIsland" domain problems.

Comment: You know I had *never* looked at the domain name expersexchange like that, but know I can never look at it without thinking of this :P Not that it is a useful site, of course...

Comment: I refer to it as "Expert Sexchange" in my head. I absolutely refuse to register for that crap, and it irritates me how high they tend to rank in Google results.

Comment: LOL.... I don't get PenIsland at first... but then whatever if you use camel case or not doesn't really help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, not a problem. As per [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) section 2.3.3, all parts of the DNS that are part of the official protocol, all comparisons between character strings (e.g., labels, domain names, etc.) are done in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: your answer is probably correct- I just want to see if practically there are some situations where the upper case will actually cause problem when the software is not written correctly?